# Steps to install Python3 on Solaris server

Tags: python-3.x

I didn't get any steps from Google to install Python3/3.x on Solaris server.

It would be great if someone provide the installation steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It you might be able to install it from here.

https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWpython33/

You can also install from source as well.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer, we tried this way, but we are failed to install additional packages/modules via pip3 (even not able to update pip as well). We got below error when we try to do that:
**
raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
**
So, we need step-by-step to install Python 3.* properly in our Solaris server

Comment: I've built a Solaris 11 VM, tried installing gcc (various versions) and failed. Happy to retire from this.

Comment: One interesting thing is: the same version of python3 is installed in our DEV Solaris server, working fine there. Whereas in PROD Solaris server we got this error

Answer (score 0):

I successfully built Python 3.11.4 from source for Solaris 5.11 in the usual way, downloading source code from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3114/ and then:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python
make
make install
```

Many tests failed, but it was still usable, at least for basic scripting.